# ffmpeg - converting one audio track of a multi-track mp4

Tags: ffmpeg, audio

I'm having a few mp4 with two audio tracks,
an english one in aac and a french one in dts.

Now I want to **convert *only* the french dts to eac3** with a single ffmpeg command.

I use

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -i input.mp4 ^
             -map_metadata -1 ^
             -map 0:0 -c:v copy ^
             -map 0:1 -c:a copy ^
             -map 0:2 -c:a eac3 -b:a 1536k ^
             -metadata:s:a:0 language=eng ^
             -metadata:s:a:0 title="Stereo" ^
             -metadata:s:a:1 language=fra ^
             -metadata:s:a:1 title="Stereo" ^
output.mp4
```

This works quite nice, **but it converts both audio tracks** to eac3, instead of leaving the first one untouched ...
What's wrong in the command?

(ffmpeg version 2023-12-23-git-f5f414d9c4-full_build-www.gyan.dev under Windows 10)

Comment: `-map` does new order of streams in output. just `ffmpeg -i in -c copy -c:a:1 eac3 -b:a:1 1637k...` same as in `-metadata:s:a:1`